# How to get values related to another from multiple sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet containing employee details

### EmployeeID | Name

### 1 | Name1

### 2 | Name2

and another sheet which has the address details

### Name | Address

### Name1 | Address1

### Name2 | Address2

Is there a way I can get the address details from the second sheet and put it in the first. The output that I need is

### EmployeeID | Name | Address

### 1 | Name1 | Address1

### 2 | Name2 | Address2

Comment: Yes. Use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: SO has documentation on the `VLOOKUP` function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel/4327/vlookup-function#t=201611240842533033494)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

`Sheet1`

```
    EmpID    Name        Addresss
1   1        El Chapo    =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2, FALSE)  // "Mazatlan, Sinoloa"
2   2        El Mencho   =VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2, FALSE)  // "Tierra Caliente, Michoacan"
3   3        El Ondeado   =VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2, FALSE)  // "Culiacan, Sinoloa"
```

`Sheet2`

```
    Name        Addresss
1   El Chapo    Mazatlan, Sinoloa
2   El Mencho   Tierra Caliente, Michoacan
3   El Ondeado  Culiacan, Sinoloa
```

- Add the `VLOOkUP` formula into the address column of `Sheet1`

Comment: False in vlookup formula? I think if you remove the third line on sheet2, sheet1 row 3 will get the address of someone else. But with the fourth variable of vlookup false it won't happen.